# Trigger Masonry after each image load in WordPress

Tags: jquery, wordpress, masonry, imagesloaded

I have Masonry working in WordPress for a page I'm creating that has about 20 images that load and then Masonry is triggered. Looks perfect, apart from when there is a slow connection speed, it loads all 20+ pictures up and only then grids them. Ideally I want masonry to trigger after each picture, like a wall is being built. I'm sure it can be done, but I can't get it to work.

The code I have used so far is below for the masonry to run is:

```
  var container = document.querySelector('#ms-container');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.ms-item',
    columnWidth: '.ms-item',
  });
```

then, I've been trying the following to get it to load after each image but it's not working,

```
  imagesLoaded().progress( container, function() {
     msnry = new Masonry( container, {
        itemSelector: '.ms-item',

     });
  });
```

I'm sure it's possible, can somebody help?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute your code when the page is fully loaded including images by using `$( window ).load()`.

```
$( window ).load(function() {

  var container = document.querySelector('#ms-container');
  var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.ms-item',
    columnWidth: '.ms-item',
  });
});
```

**EDIT**

To fire an event after loading every image

```
$('img').on('load', function(){
   var container = document.querySelector('#ms-container');
   var msnry = new Masonry( container, {
    itemSelector: '.ms-item',
    columnWidth: '.ms-item',
  });
});
```

Comment: I want the masonry to load after every image though, not once everything is fully loaded. How do I do that?